# Why we need the init_weight function in BERT pretrained model in Huggingface Transformers?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

In the code by Hugginface transformers, there are many fine-tuning models have the function `init_weight`. 
For example([here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/a9aa7456ac/src/transformers/modeling_bert.py#L1073-L1082)), there is a `init_weight` function at last.

```py
class BertForSequenceClassification(BertPreTrainedModel):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__(config)
        self.num_labels = config.num_labels

        self.bert = BertModel(config)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(config.hidden_dropout_prob)
        self.classifier = nn.Linear(config.hidden_size, config.num_labels)

        self.init_weights()
```

As I know, it will call the following [code](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/a9aa7456ac/src/transformers/modeling_bert.py#L520-L530)

```py
def _init_weights(self, module):
    """ Initialize the weights """
    if isinstance(module, (nn.Linear, nn.Embedding)):
        # Slightly different from the TF version which uses truncated_normal for initialization
        # cf https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/5617
        module.weight.data.normal_(mean=0.0, std=self.config.initializer_range)
    elif isinstance(module, BertLayerNorm):
        module.bias.data.zero_()
        module.weight.data.fill_(1.0)
    if isinstance(module, nn.Linear) and module.bias is not None:
        module.bias.data.zero_()
```

My question is **If we are loading the pre-trained model, why do we need to initialize the weight for every module?**

I guess I must be misunderstanding something here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have a look at the code for [`.from_pretrained()`](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/a9aa7456ac824c9027385b149f405e4f5649273f/src/transformers/modeling_utils.py#L490). What actually happens is something like this:

- find the correct base model class to initialise
- initialise that class with pseudo-random initialisation (by using the `_init_weights` function that you mention)
- find the file with the pretrained weights
- overwrite the weights of the model that we just created with the pretrained weights where applicable

This ensure that the layers that were not pretrained (e.g. in some cases the final classification layer) *do* get initialised in `_init_weights` but don't get overridden.

Comment: See also the related discussion in https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/4701

Answer (score 0):

`BertPreTrainedModel` is an abstract class if you check, and the error is `BertPreTrainedModel` class doesn't have the constructor even thought it is being called you may dress up this code with a PR, but make sure you create the issue first.

Comment: Yes. But I'm actually talking about the subclass: `BertForSequenceClassification`. The huggingface repo encourage people to post the issue in Stack overflow

Comment: `BertForSequenceClassification` calls abstract class constructor. So remove that call since it is not needed. `self.init_weights()` is OK. As for the move HuggingFace related things to SO I am ambivalent.

Comment: So I actually run the code. BertForSequenceClassification will call the constructor, which in turn will call the `_init_weight` function. But it appears everywhere such as the constructor of `BertForSequenceClassification` and `BertForMultiChoiceQuestion`. But my question is why we have that function if we are loading the pretrained model.